# Preencher um formulário com dados Json em jquery

Tags: jquery, json

Boa noite.

Eu tenho uma url que recebe essa estrutura em json:

```html
{
 "kind": "books#volumes",
 "totalItems": 1,
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "books#volume",
   "id": "AKs0vgAACAAJ",
   "etag": "4X6Xl91J0mQ",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/AKs0vgAACAAJ",
   "volumeInfo": {
    "title": "INTRODUÇAO A HISTORIA DO DIREITO",
    "authors": [
     "LUIZ CARLOS DE AZEVEDO"
    ],
    "description": "Esta obra aborda o conceito e importância da História do Direito, como ciência e disciplina, passando pelo Direito Grego antigo e sua expansão, à conta do Helenismo, Direito Romano e o extraordinário legado deixado pela obra dos jurisprudentes, que até hoje repercute no nosso Direito Positivo, a criação e desenvolvimento das universidades medievais, o Direito Lusitano primitivo e o que se lhe segue ao longo das três ordenações do reino, a contribuição do Direito Canônico, até alcançar a legislação do Brasil Império e a colocação de aspectos mais abrangentes, produto das sensíveis alterações ocorridas no campo do direito durante os séculos XIX e XX. Por fim, o autor apresenta os cuidados e perspectivas relativos ao terceiro milênio.",
    "industryIdentifiers": [
     {
      "type": "ISBN_10",
      "identifier": "8520339425"
     },
     {
      "type": "ISBN_13",
      "identifier": "9788520339428"
     }
    ],
    "readingModes": {
     "text": false,
     "image": false
    },
    "pageCount": 286,
    "printType": "BOOK",
    "maturityRating": "NOT_MATURE",
    "allowAnonLogging": false,
    "contentVersion": "preview-1.0.0",
    "panelizationSummary": {
     "containsEpubBubbles": false,
     "containsImageBubbles": false
    },
    "language": "pt",
    "previewLink": "http://books.google.com.br/books?id=AKs0vgAACAAJ&dq=9788520339428&hl=&cd=1&source=gbs_api",
    "infoLink": "http://books.google.com.br/books?id=AKs0vgAACAAJ&dq=9788520339428&hl=&source=gbs_api",
    "canonicalVolumeLink": "https://books.google.com/books/about/INTRODU%C3%87AO_A_HISTORIA_DO_DIREITO.html?hl=&id=AKs0vgAACAAJ"
   },
   "saleInfo": {
    "country": "BR",
    "saleability": "NOT_FOR_SALE",
    "isEbook": false
   },
   "accessInfo": {
    "country": "BR",
    "viewability": "NO_PAGES",
    "embeddable": false,
    "publicDomain": false,
    "textToSpeechPermission": "ALLOWED",
    "epub": {
     "isAvailable": false
    },
    "pdf": {
     "isAvailable": false
    },
    "webReaderLink": "http://play.google.com/books/reader?id=AKs0vgAACAAJ&hl=&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_api",
    "accessViewStatus": "NONE",
    "quoteSharingAllowed": false
   },
   "searchInfo": {
    "textSnippet": "Esta obra aborda o conceito e importância da História do Direito, como ciência e disciplina, passando pelo Direito Grego antigo e sua expansão, à conta do Helenismo, Direito Romano e o extraordinário legado deixado pela obra dos ..."
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Eu gostaria de pegar apenas os dados referente a **description** e preencher meu formulário:

```
<form id="desc" ><input type="text" name="descricao" value="" id="descricao" />
```

Como eu faria isso usando jquery? É muito complexo?

Comment: Relacionada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15414/trazer-resultado-json-em-div-com-jquery?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acordo com a estrutura json apresentada navega até à descrição fazendo:

```
objeto.items[0].volumeInfo.description
```

Exemplo:

```js
const json = `{
 "kind": "books#volumes",
 "totalItems": 1,
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "books#volume",
   "id": "AKs0vgAACAAJ",
   "etag": "4X6Xl91J0mQ",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/AKs0vgAACAAJ",
   "volumeInfo": {
    "title": "INTRODUÇAO A HISTORIA DO DIREITO",
    "authors": [
     "LUIZ CARLOS DE AZEVEDO"
    ],
    "description": "Esta obra aborda o conceito e importância da História do Direito, como ciência e disciplina, passando pelo Direito Grego antigo e sua expansão, à conta do Helenismo, Direito Romano e o extraordinário legado deixado pela obra dos jurisprudentes, que até hoje repercute no nosso Direito Positivo, a criação e desenvolvimento das universidades medievais, o Direito Lusitano primitivo e o que se lhe segue ao longo das três ordenações do reino, a contribuição do Direito Canônico, até alcançar a legislação do Brasil Império e a colocação de aspectos mais abrangentes, produto das sensíveis alterações ocorridas no campo do direito durante os séculos XIX e XX. Por fim, o autor apresenta os cuidados e perspectivas relativos ao terceiro milênio.",
    "industryIdentifiers": [
     {
      "type": "ISBN_10",
      "identifier": "8520339425"
     },
     {
      "type": "ISBN_13",
      "identifier": "9788520339428"
     }
    ],
    "readingModes": {
     "text": false,
     "image": false
    },
    "pageCount": 286,
    "printType": "BOOK",
    "maturityRating": "NOT_MATURE",
    "allowAnonLogging": false,
    "contentVersion": "preview-1.0.0",
    "panelizationSummary": {
     "containsEpubBubbles": false,
     "containsImageBubbles": false
    },
    "language": "pt",
    "previewLink": "http://books.google.com.br/books?id=AKs0vgAACAAJ&dq=9788520339428&hl=&cd=1&source=gbs_api",
    "infoLink": "http://books.google.com.br/books?id=AKs0vgAACAAJ&dq=9788520339428&hl=&source=gbs_api",
    "canonicalVolumeLink": "https://books.google.com/books/about/INTRODU%C3%87AO_A_HISTORIA_DO_DIREITO.html?hl=&id=AKs0vgAACAAJ"
   },
   "saleInfo": {
    "country": "BR",
    "saleability": "NOT_FOR_SALE",
    "isEbook": false
   },
   "accessInfo": {
    "country": "BR",
    "viewability": "NO_PAGES",
    "embeddable": false,
    "publicDomain": false,
    "textToSpeechPermission": "ALLOWED",
    "epub": {
     "isAvailable": false
    },
    "pdf": {
     "isAvailable": false
    },
    "webReaderLink": "http://play.google.com/books/reader?id=AKs0vgAACAAJ&hl=&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_api",
    "accessViewStatus": "NONE",
    "quoteSharingAllowed": false
   },
   "searchInfo": {
    "textSnippet": "Esta obra aborda o conceito e importância da História do Direito, como ciência e disciplina, passando pelo Direito Grego antigo e sua expansão, à conta do Helenismo, Direito Romano e o extraordinário legado deixado pela obra dos ..."
   }
  }
 ]
}`;

const objeto = JSON.parse(json);
let descricao = objeto.items[0].volumeInfo.description;

console.log(descricao);

document.getElementById("descricao").value = descricao;
```

```html
<form id="desc" ><input type="text" name="descricao" value="" id="descricao" />

</form>
```

Repare no entanto que eu coloquei `items[0]`. Isto é porque `items` é um array e por esse motivo podem haver vários. Logo tem de saber qual a descrição que pretende, com base na posição do item, ou apanhar todas as descrições utilizando um `for`:

```
const objeto = JSON.parse(json);

for(let item of objeto.items){
    console.log(item.volumeInfo.description); //aqui usava cada uma das descrições
}
```

Comment: muito obrigada. Funcionou da maneira que eu desejava